# Show a winform over the notification area

Tags: c#, winforms, notification-area

I want to show a winform in the very right down corner just above the system tray,

How do I do that? Here is my code:

```
public static void Notify()
{        
    Rectangle workingArea = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
    Form fm = new Form();
    fm.ClientSize = new Size(200, 200);
    int left = workingArea.Width - fm.Width;
    int top = workingArea.Height - fm.Height;
    fm.Location = new Point(left, top);
    fm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    fm.ShowIcon = false;
    fm.MinimizeBox = false;
    fm.MaximizeBox = false;
    fm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
    fm.Text = "Test";
    fm.TopMost = true;
    fm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried this and it worked for me (**note**: this code must appear *after* the form has been displayed for the first time -- for example, you can put it in the form's `Load` event handler, or simply include it after any call to `Show`):

```
Rectangle workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
int left = workingArea.Width - this.Width;
int top = workingArea.Height - this.Height;

this.Location = new Point(left, top);
```

Whether to use `WorkingArea` or `Bounds` depends on what you mean by "over": if you mean "in front of," then use `Bounds`, as it includes the area covering the entire screen (including that space occupied by the system tray); if you mean "above," then use `WorkingArea`, which just includes the user's desktop.

Also let me just clarify that you want your actual *form* displayed down there, right? If you wanted an icon in the notification area, that's what the [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) component is for.

Comment: @Data-Base: Move the lines that set the form's location to *after* you call `Show`. Windows Forms does a strange thing where it seems to ignore you when you set the `Location` property before the form's been shown for the first time.

Comment: I just used fm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; code from Hans Passant and it worked :-)

Answer (score 6):

You forgot this one:

```
        fm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

What you'll have to work on next is putting the taskbar at, say, the left side of the screen and running the code on a machine that has the video DPI setting at a different value (like 125).  You can only position the form accurately in its Load event.  Don't set the client size.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to position the form over/infront of the taskbar:

Set the forms TopMost property to true. You can use Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds to get the screen resolution then set your forms position appropriately.

---

If you just want to position the form just above the taskbar in the bottom right then you can do as follows:

In the form designer, goto Properties->Events and add the Load event to your form.

Add the following:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width;
    int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height;
    this.Bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, this.Width, this.Height);
}
```

Comment: I *think* the OP meant "over" as in "above," rather than "on top of"; so `TopMost` would not be appropriate. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: True that.. well now he has options :)